# Can nested Try Catch trigger parent catch

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am logging some errors if an error occurs in the function and my code looks like this.

```
const startFunction = async () => {
 try {
  const A = await functionA();
  const B = await functionB();
  const C = await functionC();
 } catch {
  //LOG ERROR
 }
}
```

Each of these function has its own try-catch block. So my question is, if a catch block is triggered in one of the functions (A, B or C) will the parent's (i.e. startFunction) catch block also trigger. If not then is there a way to trigger it or do I have to log all functions individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is NO in your current implementation.

If u want to populate the error from the inner functions to the top level catch block, you need to re throw the error from the inner function catch block.

Comment: So basically add ```throw error;``` in all the catches of the child function will trigger the parent catch